# Batch File for Tax year April to March

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a batch file to create 12 folders starting in April and ending in March.
I don't know how to make the date entered go to set year1= or how to make the date set year2 1 year later.
This is what i have so far.

```
@echo off

Rem( user input required say 2023 )
set /p input= Type The Year :

Rem ( 2023 from user input )
set Year1=
                            
Rem ( 2023 from user input + 1 year )
set Year2=

MKDIR %year%
CD %year%

:: GOTO FULL_MONTH

:FULL_MONTH
    
    mkdir "01 - April %Year1%"
    mkdir "02 - May %Year1%"
    mkdir "03 - June %Year1%"
    mkdir "04 - July %Year1%"
    mkdir "05 - August %Year1%"
    mkdir "06 - September %Year1%"
    mkdir "07 - October %Year1%"
    mkdir "08 - November %Year1%"
    mkdir "09 - December %Year1%"
    mkdir "10 - January %Year2%
    mkdir "11 - February %Year2%
    mkdir "12 - March %Year2%

:DONE
Dir
Pause
```

Comment: What are you trying to do that you cannot do with existing tax tools and Excel?

Comment: Hi John. I am trying to make folders 01 - April to 12 - March. all the person has to do it enter the required year when asked. there is a reason for this method ( to remove the option of people thinking they know more than they do, so this will just do it. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with Powershell using the cmdlets below.

Set the start date, then using a counter to loop through the months while creating the folders.

```ps
###Get the year entered by the user
$year = Read-Host "Please enter year"

###Set the starting date
$startdate = [DateTime] "01 April $($year)"
$count = 1

###Create folder based on the year entered by the user
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Name "$($year)"

###Change directory to the newly created folder
cd "$($year)"

While ( $count -lt 13)
{
###Create folders 
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Name "$($count.ToString('00')) - $($startdate.ToString('MMMM yyyy'))"

#Add one month
$startdate = $startdate.AddMonths(1)

#Increment the counter
$count = $count + 1

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there a reason that it cant be done in .dat file. Your option i cannot set the year to the one i require

Comment: @Alan-53 What do you mean you cannot set the year? Just replace 2023 by another year.

Comment: That has to be done in the power shell, and thats a non starter i am afraid. when i started to wright this in batch file it would ask me when run to enter a year. can power shell do this

Comment: Have just noticed that it is making the 12 files but not putting them in a folder called 2023 ( if that was the chosen year

Comment: @Alan-53 It creates folders not files. But as you don't want to use powershell, then there is no need for me to make the change to create the "Year" folder and insert them in it.

Comment: I am not saying i do not want to use powershell. i am trying to understand  ( badly ) how it works, the brief i am trying to follow is the script at the start. i am sorry that i gave the impression i did not require your assistance, this was not my intention

Comment: @Alan-53 See edit to my answer. Now, you can enter the year. Folders will be created in it.

Comment: That is truly fantastic, it is doing exactly what i wished for, you are a star, thank you so much for your time and patience with my question.

Comment: @Alan-53 You can mark the question as answered. See [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers).

Comment: Greetings i have been trying to teach myself some PowerShell and failing badly, i have posted some questions but most of the answers i get back seem very long. so i thought i would give you a try. the powershell script you provided makes a folder from the date provided by the user is the following possible to have that date then the following year so it displays without the brackets ( 2023 - 2024 ) my second question if there are files within the main folder where the script is is it possible to have them copied to the 12 folders that the script makes ?? Thankyou.

Comment: @Alan-53 The rules of the forum don't allow questions within questions or comments.. You need to ask another question and refence (post a link mentioning) this one. Like that others or myself can try to answer it.